# The method 'getSessionId' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAnalyticsPlatform'

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics

I got this error when tried to update Flutter package

[image]

Detail error

```
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics-10.8.0/lib/src/firebase_analytics.dart:81:22: Error: The method 'getSessionId' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAnalyticsPlatform'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```